# How to fix Parse query, which is returning Nullpointerexception with code =-1?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I am trying to fetch data using ParseQuery.But findInBackground() method is always returning NullPointerException. 
Here is the code snippet:

```
ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo ni = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();
        if ((ni != null) && (ni.isConnected())) {
            ParseQuery<Alert> query = Alert.getQuery();
            query.whereEqualTo("category", "Emergency");
            Log.d(TAG,"before calling query");
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<Alert>() {
                public void done(List<Alert> list, ParseException exp) 
                {
                    if(exp == null){
                        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
                        {
                            Alert alert = list.get(i);
                            Log.d(TAG, "Title = "+ alert.getTitle() + " link = "+ alert.getLink());
                        }

                    } else {
                        Log.d(TAG,"no results !!"+ exp.getMessage()+" code ="+ exp.getCode());
                    }
                };

            });
        }
```

I have checked the permission also, In Table it is showing Public Read/Write ACL.

[EDIT]In my Application.java

```
ParseObject.registerSubclass(Alert.class);
Parse.initialize(this, "ABC", "XYZ");
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();
ParseUser.enableAutomaticUser();
ParseACL defaultACL = new ParseACL();
ParseACL.setDefaultACL(defaultACL, true);
```

So can anyone suggest what am I missing?

Comment: can you plz share parse table

Comment: I think you have created Alert subclass of `ParseObject`  but did not register it in Application .java, register it like `ParseObject.registerSubclass(Alert.class);`

Comment: @ParagChauhan you mean from the Data Browser ?

Comment: @ved I tried it even after this I am getting nullpointerexception, what else is missing ?

Comment: yes,make sure your table name,column name should  be same

Answer (score 2):

NullPointerException in a query only happens in 2 cases -

- The class hasn't been registered with Parse.Solution is to add the following line after `Parse.initialize` -

  `ParseObject.registerSubclass(Alert.class);`
- The class model has been changed either on parse website or in android code. Solution is to drop the table on parse dashboard.

Comment: Thanks for response ...even after adding it, still I am getting the same NullPointerException.  And what do you mean by class model has been changed ? because I haven't modified anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Tushar's reply, the other thing which I was missing, the android:name field in  tag in Manifest file.

```
<application
        android:name ="com.tutorial.Alert.SampleApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
```